# _id is pushed to the array instead of object

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

My setup is nodejs with typescript + mongoose + express. I run my mongoose query and I get a `league` document that is 2 levels deep. I need to reorder populated array `ties` that is on my first level based on certain criteria and I execute the following code

```
                        const completed = [];
                        const upcoming = [];

                        league.ties.forEach((tie, index) => {
                            if (tie) {
                                tie?.matchStatus === "COMPLETED"
                                    ? completed.push(tie)
                                    : upcoming.push(tie);
                            }
                        });

                        upcoming.sort((a, b) => (a.startDate > b.startDate) ? 1 : ((b.startDate > a.startDate) ? -1 : 0));
                        completed.sort((a, b) => (b.startDate > a.startDate) ? 1 : ((a.startDate > b.startDate) ? -1 : 0));

                        const ties = [...upcoming, ...completed];
                        console.log(ties);

                        league.ties = ties;

                        console.log(league.ties);
```

On the first `console.log` `ties` is array of objects, but in the second `console.log` `league.ties` is array of `_id`s (strings).

Does anybody know why is this happening here and why the object is not pushed?

I tried for loops, map, lodash... I temporarily moved this code to the client Angular app and it works perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `league.ties` property has been defined as `writeable: false` (read-only). When strict mode is off, it won't throw any error, but the value will not be changed also.

You can take a look at here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: I didn't set this anywhere explicitly and to be honest, I've never used it before. Any suggestions on how I can fix it?

Comment: It should be set by the library vendor. Can you assign to your own custom attribute like `league._ties` ? If the object was freeze (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). I think the only way is to assign to new variable.